# Could xcode add multiple developer account to develop different projects

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode has one developer account, and one target. Now I need to use another account to develop a different project, could I do this work on this xcode? If I can, how I make it right?

Thank you, I searched answers a lot, But didn't found any resolutions. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: go to Xcode -> preferences -> Accounts and add both accounts and you should be good to go... or am i missing something?

Comment: @Fonix could you please say more details?

Comment: Under the accounts tab in preferences, hit the `+` at the bottom and go add apple ID, not sure what other details i can add to that

Comment: ok, I find it. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

These screenshots may help you and others.

## Step 1:

[image]

## Step 2:

[image]

## Step 3:

[image]